# Let $R[X]$ be a polynomial ring over the field $R$. Suppose $q(X) = w(X) \in R[X]$. How can I show $q(a) = w(a)$ for $a \in R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $R[X]$ be a polynomial ring over the field $R$. Suppose $q(X) = w(X) \in R[X]$. How can I show $q(a) = w(a)$ for $a \in R$ ?

To give a specific example. Suppose $q(X) = a_nX^n+...+ a_1X+a_0=b(X-b_1)\cdots(X-b_n)$ is factored using the division algorithm. I know the right hand side equals the left hand side after computing the product.

But how do I know these polynomials are equal in the sense of a function $R \mapsto R$ ? How can I verify, that if I subtitute $X$ for $a \in R$ on both sides of ($=$), that the expressions give the same result ? Is it because the calculating rules for polynomials $R[X]$ are the same as the calculating rules for elements in $R$ ? - so that I can bring the right hand side to the form of the left hand side ?

Comment: You might not want to use $a_i$ on both side of that example. $$q(x)=a_nx^n+\dots +a_0 = c(X-b_1)\dots(X-b_n)$$

Comment: For a given $a$ in $\mathcal{R}$, consider the ring homomorphism : $\varphi_{a} \, : \, \mathcal{R}[X] \, \longrightarrow \, \mathcal{R}$ such that : $\forall P \in \mathcal{R}[X], \, \varphi_{a}(P)=P(a)$. Since $Q=W$ in $\mathcal{R}[X]$, applying $\varphi_{a}$ to this equality yields : $Q(a)=W(a)$.

Comment: That kind of asssumes what is to be proven, @jibounet. Essentially, the goal is to prove $\phi_a$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: Sorry. I must have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Think about what "=" means.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It's a little trickier than that. You can define $R[X]$ with $R$ non-commutative, but with $X$ commuting with all of $R$, then it isn't true that an equality of two expressions in $R[X]$ that are equal leads to the same evaluation function.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: But then these expressions aren't *equal* in the space of expressions (I guess $R[X]$ where $X$ does not commute with all of $R$). But if you're just considering elements of $R[X]$, it doesn't make sense to say they lead to different evaluation functions, because they are the same thing -- rather they don't lead to evaluation functions at all, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit of vagueness in the question. Two polynomials are equal if they have the same coefficients, so if $q(a)$ only depends on the coefficients of $q()$, then if $w(X)=q(X)$, $w(a)=q(a)$ by definition.

What the example seems to be asking is, if you have two polynomial *expressions*, and they evaluate to the same polynomial, then evaluation of the two expressions at $a\in R$ is the same, too. That's a more obtuse question. Not hard, but tedious, because it requires a lot more definitions. Once you have definitions in place, it's a fairly direct proof.

Basically, evaluation at $a\in R$ determines a function $\phi_a:R[X]\to R$. You need to prove that this function has the following properties:

$$\phi_a(bX^0)=b,\,\forall b\in R\\
\phi_a(p(X)+q(X))=\phi_a(p(X))+\phi_a(q(X))\\
\phi_a(p(X)q(X))=\phi_a(p(X))\phi_a(q(X))$$

All of these you'd have to prove using the formal definitions of addition and multiplication in $R[X]$, and the definition of $\phi_a$.

But even then, you have to define what you mean by a "polynomial expression," which is different from a polynomial, and what it means to evaluation a polynomial expression.

Again, it is all tedious, but is follows directly from definitions once you find the right ones.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. So in the top you assume that if the evaluation of $q$ at $a\in R$ depends only of the coefficients of $q$ and if $q = w$ then $q(a) = w(a)$, since they have the same coefficients by definition ?

Comment: That part is trivial, yes. But that's not the same as saying, for example, if $(X-b)(X-c)=X^2+dX+f$ then $(a-b)(a-c)=a^2+da+f$. That requires evaluation to satisfy the above conditions. That's the tedious part...